# How can I make a usable backup of the site on CD?

Tags: backups

The client would like to archive off a copy of their drupal 7 site every 6 months or so. By archiving, they are referring to copying the site (in a usable format) onto a cd.

What are some of the options for doing this?

Comment: Cd's??? What is this, the 90s. If your client really wants a backup that he can actually have, use something like http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_dropbox

Comment: What do you mean by usable ? Your client will be able to use/browse the site directly on the cd or just a normal backup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Backup and Upgrade](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module can be used to schedule automated database backups. One of those backups, combined with the codebase, gives you a full backup of the site. If this is to be burned to a disc every 6 months, I wouldn't bother automating anything - the time investment won't be worth the future time savings.

Comment: Thank you @YuriyBabenko
So are you saying it's best to burn a compelte site, including all the includes etc onto a cd? I was hoping there would be a way for the client to somehow back it all up from the front end (somehow?).

Comment: I'm not aware of any front end tools to make such backups. Some webhosts provide interfaces to schedule automatic backups, but the backups usually live on their servers. Burning backups to CDs is a pretty antiquated approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use this: http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_dropbox as it will backup directly to your dropbox account or straight into your clients computer. From there you can just burn the CD or do whatever you want with the files. You have have it automated and it can backup every couple of days or months if you like. Just set and forget it kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you @duckx
Will a non tecnhican client be able to preview the site as it was online once they burn it onto a cd? Or will they need to make configuration changes in order to browse through the site once burned onto a cd?

Answer (score -1):

@kine456 : Some years ago, after a client request, I used Server2Go (http://www.server2go-web.de/) and it works pretty well with a small Wordpress site. Stunnix may works as well (http://stunnix.com/prod/aws/).
But it is not, in both case, the way to a store a backup.